# Unexpected end of JSON input when using fs.watch() and require() NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, require, fs

When checking for a new file inside my `./Assetto1/results` folder (.json file) the code should read the new file (`result = require("[...]")`) and log it into console. But I'm always getting the same error. Even trying for 8 hours now. The same thing happens, when using `fs.readFile()` instead of `require()`. I even tried an npm module called "decache" so that I could somehow "derequire" the file. My idea was that nodejs then expects the end of the JSON file. But nothing of this helps, as well.

Take a look at my code i wrote:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.watch('./Assetto1/results/', (eventType, filename) => {
console.log("EventType:"+eventType);
    if (eventType == "rename") {
    console.log("Debug: Rename");
    console.log("./Assetto1/results/"+filename);
    result = require("./Assetto1/results/"+filename);
    console.log(result);

    }
})
```

Console Output looks like this:

```
SyntaxError: /home/Assetto1/results/2018_9_8_9_0_RACE.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:27)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at FSWatcher.fs.watch (/home/main.js:59:12)
at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:182:13)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:130:12)
```

Content of the JSON file (AssettoCorsa Race-Results):

```
{
"TrackName": "spa",
"TrackConfig": "",
"Type": "RACE",
"DurationSecs": 0,
"RaceLaps": 5,
"Cars": [
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "NoaH",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "DEU",
            "Guid": "76561198190801825",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_SB_Mobel_Boss_10",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 1,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_Porta_9",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 2,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Kunos_zp_115",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 3,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Kunos_zp_116",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 4,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_Dubai_24H_2",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 5,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_SB_Mobel_Boss_10",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 6,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_Porta_9",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 7,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Kunos_zp_115",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 8,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Kunos_zp_116",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 9,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "Skin": "Black_Falcon_Dubai_24H_2",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 10,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "Ian Loncar",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "HRV",
            "Guid": "76561198273369988",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "Skin": "solid_red",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 11,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "Skin": "jet_black",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 12,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "Skin": "0_pearl_white",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 13,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "Skin": "super_silver",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 14,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "Skin": "jet_black",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 15,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "F. Riestra.ESP.",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "76561198130349639",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "Skin": "10_sepang_blue_pearl",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 16,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "Skin": "11_suzuka_gray_metallic_t",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 17,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "Skin": "09_samoa_orange_metallic_t",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 18,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "Skin": "Brilliant_Red",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 19,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "sale7almanna3i",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "QAT",
            "Guid": "76561198139068257",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Skin": "blu_cepheus",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 20,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "raafaal1661",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "76561198857669454",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Skin": "giallo_horus",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 21,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "alexpavillanueva",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "ESP",
            "Guid": "76561198834760853",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Skin": "blu_nethuns",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 22,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "NoaH",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "DEU",
            "Guid": "76561198190801825",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Skin": "00_arancio_anthaeus",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "CarId": 23,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "Model": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Skin": "rosso_efesto",
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    }
],
"Result": [
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "BestLap": 174182,
        "TotalTime": 891017,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 0,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 2,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 3,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 4,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 5,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 6,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 7,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 8,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 9,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "Ian Loncar",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198273369988",
        "CarId": 10,
        "CarModel": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 11,
        "CarModel": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 12,
        "CarModel": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 13,
        "CarModel": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 14,
        "CarModel": "ks_nissan_gtr",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "F. Riestra.ESP.",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198130349639",
        "CarId": 15,
        "CarModel": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 16,
        "CarModel": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 17,
        "CarModel": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 18,
        "CarModel": "ks_audi_r8_plus",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "sale7almanna3i",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198139068257",
        "CarId": 19,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "raafaal1661",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198857669454",
        "CarId": 20,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "alexpavillanueva",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198834760853",
        "CarId": 21,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 1,
        "CarModel": "mercedes_sls_gt3",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "",
        "DriverGuid": "",
        "CarId": 23,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "BestLap": 999999999,
        "TotalTime": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Restrictor": 0
    }
],
"Laps": [
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Timestamp": 35470691,
        "LapTime": 180196,
        "Sectors": [
            50515,
            82440,
            47241
        ],
        "Cuts": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Tyre": "HR",
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Timestamp": 35645934,
        "LapTime": 175240,
        "Sectors": [
            48331,
            82125,
            44784
        ],
        "Cuts": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Tyre": "HR",
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Timestamp": 35824671,
        "LapTime": 178746,
        "Sectors": [
            46162,
            85482,
            47102
        ],
        "Cuts": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Tyre": "HR",
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Timestamp": 36007357,
        "LapTime": 182686,
        "Sectors": [
            46340,
            85492,
            50854
        ],
        "Cuts": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Tyre": "HR",
        "Restrictor": 0
    },
    {
        "DriverName": "NoaH",
        "DriverGuid": "76561198190801825",
        "CarId": 22,
        "CarModel": "ks_lamborghini_huracan_performante",
        "Timestamp": 36181518,
        "LapTime": 174182,
        "Sectors": [
            46693,
            81995,
            45494
        ],
        "Cuts": 0,
        "BallastKG": 0,
        "Tyre": "HR",
        "Restrictor": 0
    }
],
"Events": [
    {
        "Type": "COLLISION_WITH_ENV",
        "CarId": 22,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "NoaH",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "DEU",
            "Guid": "76561198190801825",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "OtherCarId": -1,
        "OtherDriver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": null
        },
        "ImpactSpeed": 12.305487,
        "WorldPosition": {
            "X": 415.25763,
            "Y": 38.005207,
            "Z": 847.0971
        },
        "RelPosition": {
            "X": -0.96855915,
            "Y": 0.31426933,
            "Z": -1.4876876
        }
    },
    {
        "Type": "COLLISION_WITH_ENV",
        "CarId": 22,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "NoaH",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "DEU",
            "Guid": "76561198190801825",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "OtherCarId": -1,
        "OtherDriver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": null
        },
        "ImpactSpeed": 69.01873,
        "WorldPosition": {
            "X": -449.24142,
            "Y": 30.581987,
            "Z": -1006.0361
        },
        "RelPosition": {
            "X": 0.68840855,
            "Y": -0.285217,
            "Z": 2.4184985
        }
    },
    {
        "Type": "COLLISION_WITH_ENV",
        "CarId": 22,
        "Driver": {
            "Name": "NoaH",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "DEU",
            "Guid": "76561198190801825",
            "GuidsList": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "OtherCarId": -1,
        "OtherDriver": {
            "Name": "",
            "Team": "",
            "Nation": "",
            "Guid": "",
            "GuidsList": null
        },
        "ImpactSpeed": 22.243214,
        "WorldPosition": {
            "X": 416.29285,
            "Y": 37.574894,
            "Z": 849.2622
        },
        "RelPosition": {
            "X": -0.8986338,
            "Y": -0.2784356,
            "Z": 2.0484245
        }
    }
]
}
```

So now I don't really know what I can do against it.
Maybe you guys can help me,
thanks.

Comment: So just to be sure: it's actually a valid JSON file to begin with?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is. I checked it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it says it's valid.

Comment: What happens if you do a `readFile` and log the contents of the file?

Comment: can you post the contents of the json file?

Comment: How is the file created? You probably just have a race condition with the file being created (which triggers the `fs.watch` event and reading of the file), then the JSON is written after a bit of processing, but it's already too late. Of the JSON is big and it takes time to write it all.

Comment: I think it's an empty buffer. Output looks like this: ´EventType:rename
Debug: Rename
./Assetto1/results/2018_9_9_15_28_RACE.json
<Buffer >
EventType:change
´

Comment: @jcaron that was my initial thought too, but that shouldn't happen with a rename (which is atomic)

Comment: @robertklep, yeah, I got fooled by that one for a minute, but then I checked the docs, which state that _On most platforms, 'rename' is emitted whenever a filename appears or disappears in the directory._

Comment: the problem is, that the "change" statement happens twice and the "rename" only once. so I just had chosen that instead.

Comment: @jcaron ah, yeah, that sounds like it might be the cause.

Comment: So are you waiting for the rename before reading?  Was that your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys, after reading your posts carefully, I got the idea that I just have to wait until the file is written completely. I've done that with a simple `Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, 1000);` after that, I can read out the file without a single problem. So, that's the solution for everyone else who stumbles across this problem like me.
Thanks

Comment: This appears to have solved my issue and properly delays my reading of a large-r JSON file. The file which is just dozens of lines long was substantial enough to have required this special workaround compared to a file with just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

How is the file created? You probably just have a race condition with the file being created (which triggers the `fs.watch` event and reading of the file), then the JSON is written after a bit of processing, but it's already too late. Or the JSON is big and it takes time to write it all.

Two options for you:

- the process that creates the JSON should work in another directory (but on the same filesystem). Once the file is fully written out, move it to the directory. This way, you have an atomic change, and you know that when you receive the event the file is complete.

  An alternative is to write in the same directory, but rename once finished, and have a convention for what files are temporary or final (e.g. if the file is .xxxx.tmp ignore the event).
- or whenever you receive an event for a file (`rename` or `change`):

  - cancel any previously created timer for that file
  - create a new timer for that file
  - when the timer expires, actually read the file

Comment: Both of these options are still "improved chances" fixes. Neither is really atomic nor do they remove the race condition. (The change event can still be generated just before a spike in system I/O which delays the writes indefinitely.) That said, they are both likely to make the problem go away during development.